# Multiple timers with different delays > mutliple events on complete?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, addeventlistener

I use **several timers** with **different delays** at once. Unfortunately, the timer class is not documented.

What's the best solution, to fire specific events on `TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE`?

```
var _timer:Object = new Timer(_myVAR*1000,1);
_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, eventTimerHandler);
_timer.start();

...

private function eventTimerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
  event.target.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, eventTimerHandler);
  event.target.reset();
  event.target.stop();

  // Fire specific event

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom Timer class by extending Timer class:

```
package {
import flash.utils.Timer;
public class CustomTimer extends Timer {
public var name : String;
public function CustomTimer(name: String,delay : Number, repeatCount : int = 0) {
super(delay, repeatCount);
this.name = name;
}
}
}
```

Then :

```
var customTimer:CustomTimer=new CustomTimer("foo",1000);
...
(if event.target.name == "foo")...
```